# How do I write a typeguard for a function that takes an argument that is an intersection of a Partial<T> and object?

Tags: typescript, directus, typeguards

I am using the Directus API with Typescript. With Typescript, its [API](https://docs.directus.io/reference/sdk/#typescript) calling functions return partial entities (eg. `PartialItem<Book>`), so I'm diligently checking the existence of required properties before passing the data onward.

However, I'm still getting Typescript type errors which are unrelated to Directus specifically but perhaps with how I'm handling the partial type.

Here's a simplified example with pure Typescript ([and on TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHt0GtkG8BQyRywAJgFzIDOYUoA5gNyHFjBgA2EA-JTXSCYsicAK5gAFuii9qtBs2LIADnHoQqskKIC2AI2jMAvvnwIOcKlWQAZYHqhwoATzzC5cNgmR7MWKpQY2ADaALrIALzIYYrENJ7A3nCkpEFYABSknnCUAApObHAcADxpAHzIAGR4ZHzygkYAlG5KSpLAVAB0vthdyqJUEpnZjbFEJib4MKIgCGzoIMgwEGAIEmlU6Y15UOg6HRDF+VCFJeVhFQRKUCuiUIsgEADuyLm7+1QQ6ek3VOgcADcII0ImUrq0iJ8wAAVYA6CDocTfEFg9wQoi-f5A9LBNHopS4WrIABEAEYAEwAZgALMSADRsTgQcjEgByoBWEAgiwAosB6BIwM4ALQAMURUGJRjpePxREJFBJVOpAFZ6chGVxKMToRIUABxG6eZD6zxUPTOdViSTSbWizrIADKCHQYDAyFF7AAXupHBxSFLZa1Qo0g9LSQAGKOhpRNfCTaazeaLHpYGzoZIMUUzObABZbFrEZardZ+TaNTqSbnpVNUUHgiG1zo6ODKGv1oNKYAwdIAQj0nTIjQbcqUAHox8gABJwECkLgavVLRDuyTGqvIACCuQAkiRrB8qAxkDuACKd4hGCAcT4j0dEOwOJzOTrJVJ+GujZAT5AAKmQADCADyACyu42DyyA8gAStBQHQdOMGQb+F7jGGMaXqGRhAA)):

```
interface Book {
    id: string;
    title?: string;
    author?: string;
    pages?: number;
}

class Library {
    static books: Book[] = [];
    static addBook(data: Partial<Book> & {id: string}) {
        this.books.push(data);
    }
}

function fetchBooks(): Promise<Partial<Book>[]> {
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            resolve([
                {id: "1234",title:"Nineteen Eighty-Four"},
                {id: "2345", title: "The Great Gatsby", author: "F. Scott Fitzgerald"}
            ])
        },1000)
    })
}

function bookLoadingFunction() {
    fetchBooks().then(books=>{
        books.map(b=>{
            if(!b.id){
                // Handle the fact that the API is missing ID
            }else{
                Library.addBook(b); // * COMPILE ERROR HERE *
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Even after checking, the compiler doesn't appear to be able to infer that `b.id` is defined. And I get the following error:

```
Argument of type 'Partial<Book>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<Book> & { id: string; }'.
  Type 'Partial<Book>' is not assignable to type '{ id: string; }'.
    Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
      Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Is this a limitation of the compiler, or does there exist an edge case where `b.id` could indeed still be `undefined`? And is there a way to keep the compiler happy without losing type safety?

I know the following would make the errors go away, but it's far from ideal:

```
Library.addBook(b as Partial<Book> & {id: string});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do [these approaches](https://tsplay.dev/w2ERVW) meet your needs?  The compiler doesn't narrow a whole object type by checking its property, except if that property is the discriminant of a discriminated union.  But `Partial<Book>` is not a union at all, so there's nothing to narrow it to.  The only thing narrowed when you check `b.id` is `b.id` itself, not `b`.  To work around that safely-ish you can make a new object whose parts the compiler sees as being assignable to your narrowed type (e.g., `{...b, id:b.id}`), or you make a user defined type guard to actually narrow `Partial<Book>`.

Comment: Let me know if you want these written up as an answer or if I'm missing something.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain and write up those examples. That all makes sense and has improved my understanding of discriminating unions!

I'd tried something similar to your hasId function, but just to check the type as a whole (so `isBook` in the example above).
I never would have thought of using the spread operator like that and I like how it's versitile, as it's not always (just) the ID that I need to require.
But then I like how the isId function transpiles to JS.

I think both could work with how I plan to consume the API, so I'll try both.

Comment: Yes, feel free to write an answer if you like and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were expecting that by checking the `id` property of a `Partial<Book>` object for [truthiness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), you would get the compiler [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the object from `Partial<Book>` to `Partial<Book> & {id: string}`.  Unfortunately this is not how narrowing works in TypeScript.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#16976](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16976) for a (longstanding) open feature request to support this sort of thing.

Currently if you check the value of a property like `b.id`, it will only narrow the type of the property `b.id` itself, and not the type of the containing object `b`... well, unless `b` is of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) type and `id` is its discriminant property.  But `Partial<Book>` is not a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) at all, let alone a discriminated one.  Oh well.

---

Here are the workarounds I can think of.  One is to reassemble your object from the narrowed property and the rest of the object, via something like [object spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
if (!b.id) { } else {
    const obj = { ...b, id: b.id };
    /* const obj: {
        id: string;
        title?: string | undefined;
        author?: string | undefined;
        pages?: number | undefined;
    } */
    Library.addBook({ ...b, id: b.id }); // okay
}
```

You can see that `obj` is seen to be of a type equivalent to `Partial<Book> & {id: string}` (a.k.a. `Book`).  And therefore you can call `Library.addBook(obj)` without error.  So you've given up on narrowing `b`, and are instead building a new version of `b` of an already-narrowed type.

---

If you don't want to create a new object which is essentially equivalent to the old one, you could give up on checking `if (!b.id) {}` and instead write a [user-defined type function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) that takes `b` as an input and returns a *type predicate* saying that `b` can be narrowed depending on whether the result is `true` or `false`.  For example:

```
function hasId<T extends { id?: any }>(
  x: T
): x is T & Required<Pick<T, "id">> {
    return x.id !== undefined
}
```

The `hasId()` function accepts a parameter `x` which is known to have an `id` property (or at least an optional one), and returns the type predicate `x is T & Required<Pick<T, "id">>`.  You can see it in action:

```
if (!hasId(b)) { } else {
    b // b: Partial<Book> & Required<Pick<Partial<Book>, "id">>
    Library.addBook(b); // okay
}
```

In the `else` clause, `hasId(b)` has returned `true`, meaning that `b` has been narrowed to `Partial<Book> & Required<Pick<Partial<Book>, "id">>`.  That's also equivalent to `Book` (the type `Required<Pick<Partial<Book>, "id">>` is ugly, written in terms of the [`Required<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype), [`Pick<T, K>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) and [`Partial<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) utility types, but if you go through it you'll see it is equivalent to `{id: string}`).

So here you've decided to tell the compiler how to narrow `b`, since it doesn't know how to do so itself.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHt0GtkG8BQyRywAJgFzIDOYUoA5gNyHFjBgA2EA-JTXSCYsicAK5gAFuii9qtBs2LIADnHoQqskKIC2AI2jMAvvnwIOcKlWQAZYHqhwoATzzC5cNgmR7MWKpQY2ADaALrIALzIYYrENJ7A3nCkpEFYABSknnCBfgCUbkpKksBUAHS+2OXKolQSmdl5sUQmJvgwoiAIbOggyDAQYAgSaVTpeZQAClDoOqUQADyTTmxwHAtpAHxhm4XEUIOiUH0gEADuyNOz8+npB1ToHABuEAURuwRFcYMAKsA6EHQ4lubw+7i+RHujxe6WC4IhSlwJAoyAARABGABMAGYACyogA0yDYnAglFRADlQIMIBA+gBRYD0CRgZwAWgAYkCoKjkEYCfCEUQkWRyTjcQBWQnE9hcck-CQoADiB08yCVnioemc0rEkmk5I5ZWQAGUEOgwGBkBz2AAvdSODikXkmIXEUJ5QV8onogAM-s9SiMnraHS6PT6EksAElSAsfsgIAAPSAgUjWEWkWRwECuIybdJJyg-CbIJMkawJgBkyAAShAAI6iYAHOOTRJYeNE1FkVGbMFKA5gI59JNlMjIACEESinVIEBg1NI+FDnW6wF6Pj8NnQyQYHLXEfGeyIAyGIz8YzyZUkdPSlX8kQHEIf5R0cGU96fJ6FwBgyHSSc9HHUgCk+N0igAekg5AAAkc1ILhiUVfpECtSQ1VvZAAEFJmjCtkDmKwGGQaMABEvSDRMOCoFBwIg4hzRAGhkHQPQACtIjwZAyl4vQiVFHwQL5ZoGOQSCACpkCYli2PYyh6LEpRBP4BRKIgkkuFkVTBGQAAfZA5wXJdRKUkRxCkGQ+HkXSDKMxdTlIUyzNUdRNEobR9GgfTDLTYzHOct0jGQCTIPUr47AcJxnDKZJUj8dIkV4ioBJRYCJ2DRhxJg7A4GccK+VMBi-wAycoyoWN7zyMC+Wo2ifwYvRsp8KYVmANYNj8XYa3rJsWwgNsOyWNqOq2bte37AqlEixwXFilI0iqrLoNYrA8oKtoEWDdxtqMIA)